# Is there a way to solve Stata's r(601) while looping the append for imported excel files?

Tags: stata

I am trying to append multiple Excel files into a large database by executing the following code:

```
    cls
    set more off
    clear all
global route = "C:\Users\NICOLE\Desktop\CAR"
cd "$route"
tempfile buildDB
save `buildDB', emptyok
local filenames : dir "$route" files "*.xlsx"
display `filenames'
    
foreach f of local filenames {
    import excel using `"`f'"' ,firstrow allstring clear
    gen source = `"`f'"'
    append using `buildDB'
    save `"`buildDB'"', replace
}
save "C:\Users\NICOLE\Desktop\CAR\DB_EG-RAC.dta" ,replace
```

Stata manages to append all of the files, but it also displays the following message of error:

> `file C:\Users\NICOLE.xlsx not found  r(601);`

And I do not know how to solve it, because it does not let my code run as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the output of ```display `filenames'```?

Comment: Which part of the code requests Stata to use that file? I t

Comment: @TheIceBear, this is the output: `db_cardio_ecgs_d_r.xlsxdb_cardio_ecgs_rm.01.03.21.xlsxdb_cardio_ekgs_rm_2.xlsxdb_gfcmp_sv.xlsx~.xlsx~ db dupees.xlsx`

Comment: @NickCox, thing is, the code asks stata to import all Excel files .xlsx that are inside the folder and I have no excel with that name

Comment: I can’t see that your question is consistent about which directory you are working in.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake while writing the question. The folder named CAR is located in the Desktop. The directory is *"C:\Users\NICOLE\Desktop\CAR"* and inside CAR there are different Excel files. As I wrote, Stata manages to append the all, but r(601) keeps on popping up not letting my code run. I do not know if I understand your observation. But thanks anyway

Comment: Downvoting may seem harsh but the sad fact is that this is "unclear or not useful" despite various edits and questions.

Answer (score 0):

We have deadlock here. On the face of it the filename in question is not one you write in your code, but could only be part of the result of

```
local filenames : dir "$route" files "*.xlsx"
```

But the file named isn't even in the same directory as that named. Moreover, you are adamant that the file doesn't exist and Stata according to your error report can't find it.

**The question still remains: how does Stata get asked to open a file that supposedly doesn't exist?**

My only guesses are feeble:

1. Code you are not showing is responsible.
2. You are running slightly different versions of this script in different places and getting confused. Can you replicate this error that you did get once all over again? Have you searched everywhere remotely possible on the C: drive for this file `nicole.xlsx`?

It is crucial to realise that we can test nothing here. The problem has not been presented reproducibly.